# How to reinstall default packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, purge

In an attempt to uninstall wine I ran the command `sudo apt-get purge wine*` which as you may have guessed removed many of the default packages. I am wondering if there is a way to use the installation disk to reinstall the default packages without overwriting the file system. Not sure if it makes a difference or not, but I am duel booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu *14.04* which was updated from Ubuntu *12.04*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore default packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8309/restore-default-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer to this question: [How to uninstall all but the default Ubuntu packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39658/how-to-uninstall-all-but-the-default-ubuntu-packages):

```
comm -3 <(cat filesystem.manifest | awk '{print $1}' | sort) <(cat filesystem.manifest-remove | sort) > default.txt
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | sort > current.txt
diff -u default.txt current.txt | grep "^+[^+]" | cut -c 2- > installed.txt
diff -u default.txt current.txt | grep "^-[^-]" | cut -c 2- > uninstalled.txt
```

That makes 4 files:
default.txt is the list of all default packages,
current.txt is the list of all current packages,
installed.txt is the list of all packages you have added,
uninstalled.txt is what you want to look at, it has all the packages that you've removed.

You could then do `cat uninstalled.txt | grep wine` to list all the uninstalled packages that were related to wine.

Supposedly this could install all packages you've removed, but I wouldn't count on it:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I tried that but it said 'No such file or directory - filesystem.manifest'. Where is that file located? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @wisaac407 apparently it's a file in the Ubuntu installer. [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62318117/filesystem.manifest) the file, and [here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62318117/filesystem.manifest-remove) the filesystem.manifest-remove file.

Comment: @wisaac407 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 11):

A partial answer is: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ubuntu-desktop`

This does not include things like the kernel (e.g. linux-image-generic) and the bootloader (e.g. grub).