# Locked out of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, package-management, kde, synaptic

When I start my computer and boot into Ubuntu, the Ubuntu loading sign shows up (Ubuntu 20.04), However, the lock screen doesn't... Just a black screen.

This happened after I tried to remove KDE from my system after installing and realizing it didn't suit me.
When I logged back into Gnome, things didn't look right. So I tried uninstalling most of the KDE packages using synaptic and `sudo apt autoremove`.

But still, things looked off for example the lock screen was still KDE's and the theme was mostly KDE too... So I figured that KDE packages were still lurking around...
(I fixed the theme problem by resetting the ubuntu settings.. but the KDE lock screen was still there)

Now the next step I took caused the problem I think:
I figured that I hadn't installed many packages after installing focal fossa, so using synaptic I completely removed all packages which didn't have the Ubuntu sign on them(i figured the Ubuntu sign on the second column means they were pre-installed Ubuntu packages)

After updating and restarting Ubuntu I can't see the lock screen... Just a blank screen after the Ubuntu loading sign.

I also tried entering the password and hitting enter... But nothing happens which means I think I have removed the lock screen package.

What should I do know?

> I am able to log into the terminal.

Comment: Ps I am able to log into the terminal

Comment: If your computer has a wired network connection, try following the instructions at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/8310).

Comment: @luk3yx thanks... I don't have a wired internet connection... But i do have the live usb... Will that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to run the following command in a TTY (which you can launch using Ctrl-Alt-F4):

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Should i remove Ubuntu desktop first?

Comment: You can run the command directly.

Comment: I did that but still the lockscreen is not appearing:(. Its there a way enter into Ubuntu using the tty3?

Comment: You might also want to run the following command, and then select gdm3 in the prompt:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

If it doesn't work, run the command below and then run the above command:

`sudo apt install gdm3`

Comment: No i mean the GUI Ubuntu... The normal one we get unlocking the lockscreen

Comment: Run the following command, and then select gdm3 in the prompt: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` If it doesn't work, run the command below and then run the above command: `sudo apt install gdm3`

Comment: Please report the output of the above commands.

Comment: Ya i think gdm3 had the problem... I ran sudo apt install gdm3 and it says gdm3 is already in its newest version... But sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 gives gdm.service is not active, cannot reload

Comment: Run: `sudo systemctl enable gdm3` and `sudo systemctl start gdm3`

Comment: Please report the output.